# How to negate an implication in English?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

How to negate this proposition:
"If $xy$ is irrational then either $x$ is irrational or $y$ is irrational. "

Because the negation of $p\Rightarrow q$ is $p \wedge \text{not } q$. If I translate this sentence into English, it would be "$xy$ is irrational and $x$ and $y$ are rational." It is so strange.

Comment: There is no an implication form of negation in this case?

Comment: "There exist two rationals $x, y$ such that $xy$ is irrational", or, equivalently "There exist two rationals whose product is irrational".

Comment: To state the obvious: it's not a proposition, it's not a statement.

Answer (score 3):

$P$ in this case is "$xy$ is irrational" and $Q$ is "either $x$ is irrational or $y$ is irrational". You wrote that $\lnot(P \implies Q)$ is $(P \wedge \lnot Q)$. So, colloquially, I would suggest that $\lnot Q$ is "neither $x$ nor $y$ are irrational". This colloquially gives us:

$P \wedge \lnot Q$: "$xy$ is irrational and neither $x$ nor $y$ are irrational."

Comment: Can you write your answer in the form of conditional statement?

Comment: @HassanMuhammad: No you cannot, because a conditional statement is a case of OR, while this is a case of AND. You can of course use a negated conditional; that is what $\lnot(P\to Q)$ is.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a weird question, because the statement you are trying to negate is true!

But you are right. The negation of this statement is:

There exists x and y which are rational such that xy is irrational.

Comment: You're quantifying the statement, there are no quantifiers in the question.

Comment: The implied quantifier is $\forall x \forall y$.

Comment: It could be true, we haven't defined multiplication!!!!

Comment: There is nothing wrong in negating a true statement ... we simply get a false one. :)

Answer (score 0):

"If xy is irrational then either x is irrational or y is irrational."

Negates to:

"It is not the case that if xy is irrational, then either x is irrational or y is irrational."

We have to assume equivalences or definitions to make the sort of transformations you did.  We simply don't know if those equivalences hold... we only know that we can negate such a statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's not strange at all: in ordinary language, the negation of the expression

> "If $xy$ is irrational then either $x$ is irrational or $y$ is irrational."
>
> > $(xy \notin \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow (x \notin \mathbb{Q} \vee y \notin \mathbb{Q}))$

is stated as:

> "**Is not the case that** if $x y$ is irrational then either $x$ is irrational or $y$ is irrational. "
>
> > $\neg ((x y \notin \mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow x \notin \mathbb{Q} \vee y \notin \mathbb{Q})$

which is logically equivalent to:

> " $x y$ is irrational **and** is **not the case that** either $x$ is irrational or $y$ is irrational. "
>
> > $(xy \notin \mathbb{Q}) \wedge \neg(x \notin \mathbb{Q} \vee y \notin \mathbb{Q})$

that implies:

> " $x y$ is irrational **and** $x$ is **not** irrational and $y$ is **not** irrational.
>
> > $(xy \notin \mathbb{Q}) \wedge (\neg x \notin \mathbb{Q} \wedge \neg y \notin \mathbb{Q})$"

You can see that from the above statement we can actually find two contradictions, and it is therefore an invalid one. In a formal proof, you could also use this reasoning to prove that your original statement is valid.

Also note that the above statement, in classic logic, also implies that:

> " $xy$ is irrational **and** $x$ is **rational** and $y$ is **rational**.
>
> > $x y\notin \mathbb{Q} \wedge (x \in \mathbb{Q} \wedge y \in \mathbb{Q})$"

Comment: @B Bentzen I think the O.P means the product $xy$ not $x,y$.

Comment: @Hassan The same reasoning applies: just replace '$x \notin \mathbb{Q} \wedge y \notin \mathbb{Q}$' for '$xy \notin \mathbb{Q}$' in the antecedent.

Answer (score 0):

The negated statement sounds strange because the original statement implicitly uses quantifiers (that is, they are omitted, but they are still there):

> **For all $\bf x$ and $\bf y$,** if $xy$ is irrational, then either $x$ is
> irrational or $y$ is irrational.

The negated version, however, omits them. The correct version of the negation must include the correct quantifiers:

> There exist $x$ and $y$ such that both of the following statements are true:
>
> - $xy$ is irrational,
> - $x$ and $y$ are rational.